# How to prevent spawning objects under the window height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The title says everything!
How to prevent this? I use window innerHeight to get the height.

I am using a canvas/div where the objects are spawning in. My objects are 50x50 colored cubes.
The elements are spawning outside of the "view". 
You can scroll down when they spawn under the height. That's not what I want.

Here is some code:

```
this.drawY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (windowHeight - 140) ); // 80 (Height of Point) + 10 and - 50(To be sure that the point doesn't glitch out of the window)
```

And here is my object spawn function:

```
function Points() {
this.drawY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (windowHeight - 140) ); // 80 (Height of Point) + 10 and - 50(To be sure that the points doesnt glitch out

// Colors for Points
colors = ["#0F0","#0F0","#0F0","#F00C00","#F00C00","#00E1FF"];                
rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);           

pointID++;

switch(colors[rand]) {
    case colors[0]:
        Point = $('<div id="' + pointID + '" class="point"></div>');
        $(Point).css({'right': '0', 'top': this.drawY + 50, 'background-color': colors[0]}); // Computer always count from 0

        rewardPoints[pointID]= 5;
        break;
    case colors[1]:
        Point = $('<div id="' + pointID + '" class="point"></div>');
        $(Point).css({'right': '0', 'top': this.drawY + 50, 'background-color': colors[0]}); 

        rewardPoints[pointID]= 5;
        break;
    case colors[2]:
        Point = $('<div id="' + pointID + '" class="point"></div>');
        $(Point).css({'right': '0', 'top': this.drawY + 50, 'background-color': colors[0]});

        rewardPoints[pointID]= 5;
        break;
    case colors[3]:
        Point = $('<div id="' + pointID + '" class="point"></div>');
        $(Point).css({'right': '0', 'top': this.drawY + 50, 'background-color': colors[3]}); 

        rewardPoints[pointID]= 10;
        break;  
    case colors[4]:
        Point = $('<div id="' + pointID + '" class="point"></div>');
        $(Point).css({'right': '0', 'top': this.drawY + 50, 'background-color': colors[3]});

        rewardPoints[pointID]= 10;
        break;  
    case colors[5]:
        Point = $('<div id="' + pointID + '" class="point"></div>');
        $(Point).css({'right': '0', 'top': this.drawY + 50, 'background-color': colors[5]}); 

        rewardPoints[pointID]= 30;
        break;  
}

canvasPoints.append(Point); // Spawn Point

}
```

Still the objects are spawning out of my window. Help me! :-(

Comment: Please define "objects" in your context. This question isn't as clear as you think it is.

Comment: Do you mean that the DOM elements are being created outside of the window?

Comment: Seeing `drawY` i assume you're talking about canvas? am i right?

Comment: I use canvas yes. My objects are 50x50 colored cubes.
The elements are spawning outside of the "view". You can scroll
down when they spawn under the height.

Comment: @247errorsnl Please edit your question and add that info, and anything else to it.

Comment: @LeeTaylor Added. I hope it's enough information for you guys?